Activity recreating on first locale change
I am using this code to change app locale
AppCompatDelegate.setApplicationLocales( LocaleListCompat.forLanguageTags(languageCode) )
and also adding
android:configChanges="locale|layoutDirection|screenSize"
this line to my activity manifest
the problem is that activty is recreating on first launch and then it is working without recreation and locale change, how can i prevent from first launch recreation ?
